# Fishpig Wordpress Magento addons Custom post types & taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I'm very new to Magento.
I want WordPress post and custom post type into Magento. For that, I've installed Magento WordPress Integration extension. I got success to fetch posts from WordPress which I've installed in Magento root using the same database which had been used by Magento. For custom post type I've also purchased Post Types & Taxonomies add-ons of fishpig and installed it on my server.

Now, here is my question, how to get custom post type from WordPress into Magento? Also, I want to maintain URL structure as well. URL structure which I would like to maintain is... suppose my Magento site is like this www.example.com and my posts and custom posts like news, press, team etc... my URL would be www.example.com/blog for posts and www.example.com/news, www.example.com/press, www.example.com/team etc...

Hope this description is sufficient to get my problem. For getting this thing done I've tested all possible ways. I've also referred these URLs http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/advanced-custom-coding/#post-models, [enter link description here](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/post-types-taxonomies/custom-templates/) but I can't understand from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Have you already created your new post types? If not, install the [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) and use this to create a new post type. Ensure that you set the Archive option to True/Yes (this creates the page that lists of the posts for the new custom type).

When you have created a custom post type, create a new post for that type in the WordPress Admin and save it. You should then be able to click the URL it generates for the post and see it in Magento.

If you get a 404 error at this point, ensure that you have latest version of Magento WordPress Integration installed and that you have no errors at System > Configuration > WordPress in the Magento Admin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have created post in Wordpress using both code and Custom Post Type UI. I've set Has Archive Option to true in CPT UI. I don't get 404 error. but I can't understood how can I get the posts for new post on magento. Do I add any code into xml or Do I have to create any phtml files or any thing else? Do I compulsory use TwentyTwelve Wordpress theme? as this extension shows me only error of theme

Comment: You say you don't get a 404 anymore; do you have a link to the custom post that doesn't 404?